# SeleniumRc - Firefox fails to start

Tags: selenium-rc

I am using Selenium-Rc 1.0.3 with Firefox 3.6.8. I started Selenium-Rc with -firefoxProfileTemplate option after creating a different Firefox profile for it. Each time I start the test and check the server-side log,  I get this error;

```
14:53:49.881 DEBUG [12] org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet - got condition? : false
14:53:49.881 DEBUG [12] org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet - waiting for window 'null' local frame 'null' for 810 more secs


15:07:20.273 DEBUG [12] org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet - got condition? : false
15:07:20.273 DEBUG [12] org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet - waiting for window 'null' local frame 'null' for 0 more secs
15:07:20.274 DEBUG [12] org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet - waiting for condition for 1000 more ms
15:07:21.274 ERROR - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data
org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: timed out waiting for window 'null' to appear
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.waitForLoad(FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.java:569)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.waitForLoad(FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.createNewRemoteSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:373)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.getNewBrowserSession(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:733)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.doCommand(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:399)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handleCommandRequest(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:370)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handle(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:129)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:245)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
15:07:21.275 INFO - Killing Firefox...
15:07:21.285 INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser on session null
15:07:21.274 DEBUG [12] org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet - got condition? : false
15:07:21.274 ERROR [12] org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data
org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: timed out waiting for window 'null' to appear
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.waitForLoad(FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.java:569)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.waitForLoad(FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.createNewRemoteSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:373)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.getNewBrowserSession(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:733)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.doCommand(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:399)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handleCommandRequest(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:370)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handle(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:129)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:245)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
15:07:21.275 INFO [12] org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher - Killing Firefox...
15:07:21.283 DEBUG [12] org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet - clearing queue set
15:07:21.285 INFO [12] org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser on session null
15:07:21.286 DEBUG [12] org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext - Handled by org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
15:07:21.286 DEBUG [12] org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection - RESPONSE:
```

Please, any idea on how to solve this? I will appreciate every helpful suggestion.

Regards,

Manjide

Comment: What OS are you running this on?  Is it being run headless?

Comment: Sorry that I was away and couldn't reply to your posting. I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

run selenium server in interactive mode . so just run this command
java -jar selenium-server-jar -interactive -singleWindow

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem in Ubuntu.  Temporarily launching the selenium server as root did the trick for me:

```
sudo java -jar selenium-server.jar
```